# Wordpress add categories statistics in my admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, statistics

I was googled "wordpress categories statistics" but I can't find any way to add it in my panel in my wordpress blog.
I tried "jetpack" and "Google Analytics for WordPress" but they did not achieve the desired purpose
I need to know how many posts are published in a category called "news" for example, today or yesterday. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a ready solution for you. [This my plugin, that show same statistics.](https://github.com/dfinchenko/wp-categories-statistics)

If you need more modificated, I can make it for you!